# Unable to find Azure Spatial Anchor on another HoloLens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I am having trouble implementing shared experience using Azure Spatial Anchors. I followed the Microsoft tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-sharing-05) and it is working locally on one HoloLens 2. But when I try to share anchor on one HoloLens 2 and get it from another HoloLens 2 in the same room the watcher can't seem to find it. No error is thrown and last debug message I get is "Watcher created" and "Looking for Azure anchor... please wait..." [Debug Window Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozHbZ.png) . I tried going to different rooms multiple times but that didn't help.
I'm using:
Unity 2020.3.12 LTS,
MRTK 2.7.2,
ASA 2.10.0-preview1,
OpenXR 1.0

Answer (score 1):

From telemetry, it seems that your HL2 devices are not sending any visual data to the service to locate the anchor, which would explain the behavior you're seeing.

Please create a new issue at the ASA samples repository, and we can investigate the problem further:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues

Comment: Thank you! The issue was resolved there. https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues/291 Updating ASA SDK Core and ASA SDK for Windows to v2.10.2 solved the problem.